# Scroll content without scrollbar using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to scroll a content child of a fixed div. I am trying to scroll without the scroll bar being visible (using the mouse scroll). I have pretty much tried all the solutions I came across on Stackoverflow and on google in general but no success.

Please find here the JSfiddle of the problem:

THE CSS:

```
#left-panel {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:220px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

JS FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Xg5v/2/

Please note that the parent div must be fixed and must be 100% height.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: All of your examples and solutions below worked for me. But I had to select the one that worked first. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could kinda hack it cross-browser by expanding the width of the nav element and force scrollbars. Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Xg5v/4/).

```
nav {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width: 110%;         /*  <----   */
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;   /*  <----   */
}
```

Of course, you'll want to adjust the percentage to your needs or use `calc( 100% + 15px )`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following :

```
#left-panel {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:220px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

nav {
   height:100%;
   overflow-y:auto;
   overflow-x:hidden;
   width:100%;
   padding-right: 15px;      
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Xg5v/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You can style the scrollbar using webkit.

```
element::-webkit-scrollbar {styling here}
```

In order to hide the scroll bar on your nav element you can use the following:

```
nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:0!important;
}
```